# Distance between any two points in a compact metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I am given the following problem:

> Show that if a metric space (X,d) is compact (meaning X is compact
>   with respect to the metric d), then there exist points a,b ∈ X such
>   that d(a,b) = sup{d(x,y) : x,y in X}. (Hint: You’ll need to use the fact
>   that (X,d) is compact twice. In particular, this means that every
>   compact metric space has an upper bound on how far away two points can
>   be)

However, I am not sure if the problem has left out $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Does the statement hold in a general metric space?

Secondly, how might one go about proving this?

Comment: No need to assume $X\subset\mathbb{R}$.
I think this will give you the answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124838/diameter-on-a-compact-metric-space

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to use compactness once. Consider the given distance function $d:X\times X\to \mathbb R$. If $X$ is compact, then so is $X\times X$ (this is the easy part of Tychonoff that can actually be proved easily without recourse to anything complicated). Now, a continuous real-valued function on a compact set attains a maximum. The distance function is always (uniformly) continuous.

In case you are looking for a proof that avoids any topology: A metric space is compact if every sequence in it admits a convergent subsequence. Prove that if $X$ is compact, then so is $X\times X$. Then, suppose the distances were unbounded. Construct a sequence of pairs of points $(x_i,y_i)$ with unbounded distances. Extract a subsequence, use continuity of the distance function and get a contradiction. Thus the distances are bounded. Let $s$ be the supremum of all distances. Now construct a sequences of pairs as above that converges to the supremum. Extract a convergent subsequence, apply continuity of the distance function, and show the supermum is attained at the limit of the extracted subsequence.